# Well-posedness of a certain linear Cauchy-problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I am interested in solutions to the linear Cauchy problem
$$\Bigl(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} + a(t, x)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \sum_{j=1}^n b_j(t, x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\Bigr)u(t, x) = h(t, x)$$
with initial data
$$u(0, x) = u_0(x), ~~~~~~~~~ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(0, x) - u_1(x).$$
Of course, in the case that everything is analytic, there is a unique analytic solution by Cauchy-Kowalewskaja, but I canot make this assumption.

If (hopefully), there is a unique solution for (at least some) given data, I would also be interested in growth estimates on the solution in $t$ (in fact, I do have that the $b_j$ have exponential decay in $t$).

Any hints and references on how to tackle this problem will be appreciated!

Comment: This is like solving the heat equation "sideways," which is well known not to be a well posed problem.

Comment: In what way would that be the same? What exactly do you mean by solving the heat equation sideways?

Comment: Take the standard heat equation in 1 dimension, interchange $t$ and $x$, you get something that looks like your equation. It does not have continuous dependence on initial data: see e.g. Problem 15 of [this set of notes](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M545/3Heat.pdf).